# Is this typical Ajax behavior? If so, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have two views handled by one controller.

view A-

```
<div id="landingzone" style="width:500; height:300;">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
  });
  var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='/images/load.gif' alt='loading...' width='40px' />";

//  load() functions

  $("#show").click(function() {
    var loadUrl = "/reports/ref_table_template/"
    loadUrl = loadUrl + $('#lender option:selected').val();
    $("#landingzone").html(ajax_load).load( loadUrl + " #mydom > *" );
    });
</script>
```

view B-

```
<div style="position: relative; align: float-right;" id="nodom1">
  Nothing here should matter!  I should be able to write profanities and not see them.
</div>

<div id="mydom" style="position: relative; align: float-left;">
  This text should render.
</div>

<div id="nodom2">
  This should also not render.
</div>
```

What I would expect from the research I've done is that when Ajax does its thing, it takes only the data from the "mydom" DOM within view B, and load it into "landingzone".  However, it actually loads everything from "mydom" down- so it also loads "nodom2" as well.

Is this typical Ajax behavior?  If so- why does it do this?  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's typical. This is what jquery is doing internally:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/reports/ref_table_template/",
    success: function(responsestring){
        theelement.html($("<div />").html(responsestring).find("#mydom > *"));
    }
})
```

It loads the target page, then filters it by the selector and sets it as the content of the selected element.

In your case, your selector should simply be `#mydom` rather than `#mydom > *`.

If you wanted to have your server only return your target html and not all of it, you'll have to modify the serverscript to make it only return your target html. there's nothing jquery/javascript can do to accomplish that.

Comment: Also +1 for explanation.  So, if I'm reading you correctly, the selector would almost serve as a starting flag- essentially, start at #selecter, grab everything to EOF and return.  Am I on the right path here?

Comment: No, it literally only grabs elements matched by the selector and the contents of those elements. With my selector, it would get `<div id="mydom" style="position: relative; align: float-left;">
  This text should render.
</div>` Since jquery doesn't have a selector to select text, you can't select just the text within the div. With your selector i'd expect it to get nothing.

Comment: Because of the '> *' in my selector, I assume? That '> *' was something I picked up from http://css-tricks.com/ajax-load-container-contents/ and decided to fool around with.  Originally, I didn't have that in the code, but either way, it still performs the same.  Element matching was exactly what I expected-- just grab the element by that ID; but it also grabs the div with a different ID below it.  That's the part I had trouble understanding.

Comment: Of course, it could also be because I failed to end the table with `</table>` edit: (I didn't include the table code before as it contained sensitive company information) ... wouldn't rule that out.  In fact, I believe that was the problem this whole time.. Thanks for the added insight into Ajax- if I hadn't made that blunder, I wouldn't have known how it actually functions!

Comment: that's very likely to cause that kind of problem

Comment: I will mark this as my answer, despite epascarello's precise and valid answer, it was easier for me to understand this one.

Comment: @KevinB what if i want to make a check availability for username as example ? i tried but it was not work, do you know a way to do it from scratch ?

Comment: Sure, send an ajax request to the server with the target username, on server see if it's available and return true or false back to the browser, and on browser receive that true/false value and act upon it.

Answer (score 2):

Because the only way to get that piece of the page is to load it into memory and query it out.

If you do not want all the content to be fetched, than make the server only return the data you want.

Comment: This makes perfect sense- but I thought that's what Ajax does to begin with.  It loads the whole page, then it selects the specified DOM & only renders that, right?  So, considering that I may be misunderstanding how it works, why am I getting from the top of the DOM to the bottom of the page, instead of just the DOM?  Also, "make the server only return the data you want."- this is exactly what I'd like to figure out how to do.  If Ajax .load function does not do this, what method can I use?

Comment: It is the only way to do it with the clientside. The  XMLHttpRequest gets a string, it needs to be turned into a tree so it can be queried so you need to set the text to a node and render it so you can query it. There is no way to avoid it other than making the server only return what you need.